# Import Excel File into SSMS But Text Cut Off

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssms

I am using the `Import and Export Wizard` to import values from an Excel file into SSMS, but when I look at some of the values, it looks like they are cut off after about 255 characters.

I am importing this into a table as `varchar(max)`, so why am I losing some of the values?

- SQL Server Management Studio Version: 15.0.18338.0
- Excel File Type: .xlsx

Comment: When the wizard is looking at Excel it will only check the first "X" number of rows, try moving one of the rows with > 255 characters to the top of the spreadsheet and import again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happened to me too when I used Import and Export Wizard but actually , I solved it with these solutions :

- Ensure the all columns in table no one has identity type.
- Ensure some of fields need to be varchar(max).
- Be careful to make the columns is null "choice" for test.